# MySQL GROUP BY - wrong dates

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Ik have a table AHTLETE_TABLE with username, athlete_time and athlete_date
I want to return the fastest time (MIN(athlete_time) of every athlete. I am using this query:

```
$sql = " SELECT *, MIN(athlete_time) AS minimum 
FROM (".ATHLETE_TABLE.")
WHERE athlete_time <> '00:00:00'
GROUP BY athlete_username
ORDER BY minimum ASC";
```

I get the fastest times with the wrong dates. I don't know what I have to do.
Thank anyway for your help.

Comment: `ATHELTE_TABLE` or `ATHLETE_TABLE` ?

Comment: what you mean wrong dates? show us data sample, current result and desire output.

Comment: So there are multiple records per athlete and you want to pull there fastest time and what date it was achieved on? I would probably not group by and just order by `athlete_time` then do distinct on the username.

Comment: I just corrected the table name.

The ouput:
Tim 00:20:30 on 10-10-2015

Its should be Tim 00:20:30 on 20-10-2015

Comment: dont put output on comment, just update your question with the complete info

Comment: see http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_format.php for reference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your group by is bringing a random date.

You need calculate the min value in a derivated query and join back to get the whole row.

```
SELECT AT.*
FROM ATHLETE_TABLE AT
JOIN (SELECT username, MIN(athlete_time) AS minimum 
      FROM ATHLETE_TABLE         
      GROUP BY username
     ) T
  ON AT.username = T.username
 AND AT.athlete_time = T.minimum
```

**NOTE**: be carefull of what you want to do if a same user have ties for  `MIN(athlete_time)`, in this case will show both times.

Comment: Sara remember accept the answer and upvote if this solve your problem.